# Odd Rails Routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am getting an `undefined method stripe_managed_accounts_path` when trying to create a new resource via typical rails forms.  Below is my code, I am dumbfounded, cannot figure it out.

Controller

```
class StripeManagedAccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_printer!

  def new
    @stripe_managed_account = StripeManagedAccount.new(printer_id: current_printer.id)
  end
end
```

model

```
class StripeManagedAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :printer
end
```

views/new

```
<h1>Create New Stripe Managed Account</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

view/form

```
<h5>inside the form</h5>

<%= form_for @stripe_managed_account do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

routes

```
resources :printers, only: [:show, :edit, :update] do
    resources :stripe_managed_accounts
end
```

error

```
`undefined method 'stripe_managed_accounts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc627d342b8>:0x007fc62b36e108>`
```

routes

```
printer_stripe_managed_accounts GET    /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts(.:format)          stripe_managed_accounts#index
                                    POST   /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts(.:format)          stripe_managed_accounts#create
 new_printer_stripe_managed_account GET    /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts/new(.:format)      stripe_managed_accounts#new
edit_printer_stripe_managed_account GET    /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts/:id/edit(.:format) stripe_managed_accounts#edit
     printer_stripe_managed_account GET    /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts/:id(.:format)      stripe_managed_accounts#show
                                    PATCH  /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts/:id(.:format)      stripe_managed_accounts#update
                                    PUT    /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts/:id(.:format)      stripe_managed_accounts#update
                                    DELETE /printers/:printer_id/stripe_managed_accounts/:id(.:format)      stripe_managed_accounts#destroy
```

and it is highliting this line `<%= form_for @stripe_managed_account do |f| %>`

I have grepped the entire code base for `stripe_managed_accounts_path` and it is no where.  I am at odds end...

UPDATE:::

If I add that route it disappears???  Why is it looking for that route.  Is it becasue of how I named my fodlers, etc??

Comment: provide rake:routes, it might be a clue

Comment: this is interesting `#<#<Class:0x007fc627d342b8>:0x007fc62b36e108>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nesting `stripe_managed_accounts` inside `printers` on your routes file. If you take a look at the output of `rake routes`, you can see that there isn't a path for `stripe_managed_accounts_path`.

You can either use the shallow option on the `stripe_managed_accounts` resource or adjust your form to include the printer which the managed account will belong to.

```
#controller
class StripeManagedAccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_printer!

  def new
    @stripe_managed_account = current_printer.build_stripe_managed_account
  end

  def create
    current_printer.stripe_managed_accounts.create stripe_managed_account_params
    # handle response
  end

  def stripe_managed_account_params
    params.require(:stripe_managed_account).permit([list of attributes])
  end
end

#form
<h5>inside the form</h5>

<%= form_for [current_printer, @stripe_managed_account] do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

That will generate the proper url, nesting the `stripe_managed_account` inside the current printer.

For has_one association reference http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference